# NW.js - nwbuild not opening on windows

Tags: javascript, build, nwjs

I have an application building in Nw.js. Its almost done, but now facing an issue. While on clicking nw.exe on code (development) it is opening very fast, within in 2 seconds. But when I create a build using `nwbuild -p win64 .` , it is taking a lot time of time, say a minute to open and giving a feeling that app is opening itself.

The code base when built, the .exe is 21 MB size. Appreciate, if some one could help me to understand why this happens and what to make it open faster.

Answer (score 0):

nwbuild is not recommended by official now, maybe try [nwjs-builder-phoenix](https://github.com/evshiron/nwjs-builder-phoenix) or create you own distribute script. As I remember, nwjs-builder-phoenix also not handle `node_modules` folder size very good.

Here is how I distribute my package:

1. copy NW.js binaries client to `dist` folder
2. copy my working source project into a folder named `package.nw`(Windows) or `app.nw` in `nwjs.app/Contents/Resources/`(MacOS)
3. run `npm prune --production` under the path you just copy your source into. https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/prune.html
4. using npm package `plist`(for MacOS) or `rcedit`(for Windows) to change the binaries client's information about version, nanme, author ..etc

For mac these is alot of things needs to be changed if you want to publish to appstore http://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/For%20Users/Advanced/Support%20for%20Mac%20App%20Store/